# refer the arn created from previous resource

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to add the resource arn of the policy created from the step one to the second step. But i am unable to refer the arn from resource one to resource two. i tried with !ref and getattr,both are not working. are there any work around to this?

Below the cloudformation template i am trying to execute.

```
    Parameters: 
      AccountID: 
        Type: 'String'
        Default: "123465646"
        Description: "account id where the resources will be created"
    Resources:
      ssmPolicyEc2Manage: 
        Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
        Properties: 
          Description: "This policy will be attached to EC2 running ssm agent"
          Path: "/"
          PolicyDocument: 
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement: 
            - 
              Effect: "Allow"
              Action: "iam:PassRole"
              Resource: 
                  - !Join [ "", [ "arn:aws:iam::", !Ref AccountID, ":role/ssm_role_policy" ] ]

      snsPolicyRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:    
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect : "Allow"
                Principal:
                  Service :
                    - "ssm.amazonaws.com"
                    - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                Action:
                    - "sts:AssumeRole"
          Path: "/"
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - "HERE INCLUDE THE RESOURCE ARN CREATED FROM THE PREVIOUS RESOURCE I.E,ssmPolicyEc2Manage "
        DependsOn: ssmPolicyEc2Manage
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you simply try `Ref: ssmPolicyEc2Manage`? Do you have any particular error messages?

Comment: thank you. your comment was helpful. i was trying with !Ref instead just Ref

Comment: @PruthviRaj `!Ref` and `Ref:` are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

!Ref ssmPolicyEc2Manage will return the ARN of the resource. You can take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-managedpolicy.html) for better understanding.